# Derivative of floor function

Tags: calculus, wolfram-alpha

I thought the derivative of function $\text{floor}(x)$ should be $\infty$ for integer values of $x$ and 0 elsewhere. But [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+floor%27%28x%29+from+0+to+2) plot showed something different. Is there any explanation?

Comment: It does not exist for integer values, and it is $0$ elsewhere. Explanation: don't trust Wolfram too much.

Comment: @Julien wolfram alpha now seems to be giving the correct answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative+of+floor%28x%29

Comment: @Julien (I'm not the original poster) I guess you can then say the derivative is $\frac0{x \mod 1}$ since it is undefined for integer values of $x$ ($\frac00$ is undefined) and $0$ elsewhere..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Alpha plot is badly wrong.  The derivative of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is 0 at non integers and not defined at integers.  You would have to ask the people at Wolfram why this happens.

Update:  Alpha has changed its behavior in response to the input.  It clearly now does not understand the request at all.

Comment: It does that for some other graphs as well.

Answer (score 9):

It's probably calculating the derivative [numerically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) instead of symbolically.  An approach that gives a good approximation for functions that actually are differentiable, but behaves weird when the function is discontinuous.

For example, using a simple centered difference approximation $f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{2h}$, with $h = 0.05$, gives $f'(1) \approx \frac{f(1.05) - f(0.95)}{0.1} = \frac{1 - 0}{0.1} = 10$.  This is nonsense, but an artifact of the computation.

Answer (score 4):

If you try asking Wolfram Alpha to differentiate the floor function, it will just output "Floor'(x)". If you force Wolfram Alpha to plot the derivative of the floor function, I think what Wolfram Alpha does is it as an infinite sum of dirac deltas, so that when you integrate, you can still get back the floor function. See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiracDelta.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html

Clearly that's not what you had in mind when you asked Wolfram Alpha to plot the graph, but well...

Answer (score 0):

the derivative of a step function $$ \sum_{n\le x}a(n) $$ is always defined in the sense of distribution as  $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a(n)\delta (x-n) $$